# iOS Browsers not respecting HTML5 audio preload tag

Tags: ios, html, mobile-safari, html5-audio

Has anyone else noticed that Safari (and even Chrome) for iOS attempt to preload all audio tags even if you use the preload="none":

```
<audio src="test.mp3" preload="none"></audio>
```

Desktop browsers appear to work correctly, but as soon as I load the page from the iPhone the **Apache server registers a request for the file**.

Comment: `preload="none"` works for me on iOS Safari and iOS Chrome (iOS 7). What makes you think it preloads?

Comment: @blex how are you testing? Are you looking at your server logs?

Comment: It makes a request (seen in log) but if I wait and press play, the file then takes a while to load, so I think it just downloads the metadata.

Comment: some info [**here**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/#list4)

Comment: @blex that page appears to say the exact opposite of what I am seeing

Comment: My assumption is that it loads the metadata, not the whole file. (At least, that would explain that contradiction)

Answer (score 8):

According to Apple Docs, Mobile Safari never loads music file or metadata until user touch is detected. This is to make sure a webpage doesn't request a lot of music or data to be downloaded on mobile devices which might take up a lot of mobile data. So preload tag is essentially always set to "none" in mobile Safari regardless of what your code has. Here's the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html) to the docs where they explain everything.

> **Quote straight from the docs** "Note: The preload attribute is supported in Safari 5.0 and later. Safari on iOS never preloads."